# "Column's children must not contain null values" error on hot reload and restart in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, hot-reload, flutter-widget

I am trying to  build a dynamic Authentication Screen i.e I have a form which shows fields depending on whether the form `isLoginForm` or not.

I tried initialising the `CustomForm` class in the `State` of my `LoginScreen` but everytime I hot reload or restart, the app says that the column's child is null i.e. the `CustomForm` is `null`.
I initialized the form in the `void initState()` because it also takes `textControllers` as one of its parameters in the constructor.

Here is the code for `LoginScreen` class:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  TextEditingController _nameController;
  TextEditingController _emailController;
  TextEditingController _passwordController;
  CustomForm _form;
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

 @override
  void initState() {
    widget._nameController = TextEditingController();
    widget._emailController = TextEditingController();
    widget._passwordController = TextEditingController();
    initForm();
    widget._nameController.addListener(_nameControllerListener);
    widget._emailController.addListener(_emailControllerListener);
    widget._passwordController.addListener(_passwordControllerListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  void initForm() {
    widget._form = CustomForm(
      isLoginForm: false,
      nameController: widget._nameController,
      passwordController: widget._passwordController,
      emailController: widget._emailController,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget._nameController.removeListener(_nameControllerListener);
    widget._nameController.dispose();
    widget._emailController.removeListener(_emailControllerListener);
    widget._emailController.dispose();
    widget._passwordController.removeListener(_passwordControllerListener);
    widget._passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _nameControllerListener() {
    print("(_nameValue Call)__name value is: ${widget._nameController.text}\n");
  }

  void _emailControllerListener() {
    print(
        "(_emailValue Call)__email value is: ${widget._emailController.text}\n");
  }

  void _passwordControllerListener() {
    print(
        "(_passwordValue Call)__password value is: ${widget._passwordController.text}\n");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.init();
    

    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: SafeArea(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 1920.h - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
                  child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                    SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/login/top_left.svg',
                        width: 320.w),
                    Positioned(
                        bottom: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                            'assets/svg/login/bottom_right.svg',
                            width: 320.w)),
                    Center(
                      child: Container(
                          width: 793.w,
                          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(height: 223.h),
                            Text('Login',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 100.sp,
                                    fontFamily: 'Avenir')),
                            SizedBox(height: 60.h),
                            SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/login/main_image.svg',
                                width: 266.w),
                            SizedBox(height: 143.h),
                            widget._form,
                          ])),
                    )
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

And here is the code for the `CustomForm` class:

```
class CustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomForm(
      {Key key,
      this.isLoginForm,
      this.nameController,
      this.emailController,
      this.passwordController})
      : super(key: key);
  bool isLoginForm;
  final nameController;
  final emailController;
  final passwordController;

  @override
  _CustomFormState createState() => _CustomFormState();
}

class _CustomFormState extends State<CustomForm> {
  CustomTextFormField _name;
  CustomTextFormField _email;
  CustomTextFormField _password;
  final authBloc = AuthBloc();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _name = CustomTextFormField(
      hint: "Your Name",
      isPassword: false,
      isLoginForm: widget.isLoginForm,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      textController: widget.nameController,
      stream: authBloc.nameStream,
      onChanged: authBloc.nameSink,
    );
    _email = CustomTextFormField(
      hint: "Your Email",
      isPassword: false,
      isLoginForm: widget.isLoginForm,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      textController: widget.emailController,
      stream: authBloc.emailStream,
      onChanged: authBloc.emailSink,
    );
    _password = CustomTextFormField(
      hint: "Password",
      isPassword: true,
      isLoginForm: widget.isLoginForm,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
      textController: widget.passwordController,
      stream: authBloc.passwordStream,
      onChanged: authBloc.passwordSink,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.init();
    double rectangleGap1h = widget.isLoginForm ? 20.h : 10.h;
    double rectangleGap2h = widget.isLoginForm ? 23.h : 14.h;
    double btnHeight = widget.isLoginForm ? 133.h : 120.h;
    String submitBtnText = widget.isLoginForm ? "Login" : "Sign Up";
    String redirectText = widget.isLoginForm ? "Sign Up" : "Login";
    String bottomQuestionText = widget.isLoginForm
        ? "Don\'t have an account?"
        : "Already have an account?";
    int _defaultRadioVal = -1;

    return Form(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Visibility(
            visible: !widget.isLoginForm,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                //RADIO GROUP
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Radio(
                        value: 0,
                        groupValue: _defaultRadioVal,
                        onChanged: (int i) {}),
                    Text('Customer'),
                    Radio(
                        value: 0,
                        groupValue: _defaultRadioVal,
                        onChanged: (int i) {}),
                    Text('Designer'),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: rectangleGap1h),
                _name,
                SizedBox(height: rectangleGap1h),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          _email,
          SizedBox(
            height: rectangleGap1h,
          ),
          _password,
          SizedBox(height: rectangleGap1h),
          _buildSubmitButton(submitBtnText, btnHeight),
          SizedBox(
            height: rectangleGap2h,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 71.w),
              Text(
                bottomQuestionText,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: kHintTextColor,
                  fontSize: 43.sp,
                  fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                redirectText,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                  fontSize: 43.sp,
                  fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 71.w),
              // Visibility(
              //     visible: !widget.isLoginForm,
              //     child: _buildBottomSignUpContainer()),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Every time I rerun the app it seems to work but on hot reload and restart it doesn't work.

Will this work otherwise or will this thing cause an error later as well?
Is this just because on hot reload the `initState()` method is not called?
Please help
Thank you :)

Comment: somewhere in your code you are passing a null value to the children parameter of the Column widget, your stack trace tells you which column, hot reload rebuilds the app, therefore may be somewhere in the build logic you are setting the children parameter to null

Comment: I understand that the error is caused by setting the children parameter to null and that child is the CustomForm itself. But as you can see I am initializing it in the initState() so that shouldnt be a problem?

Comment: you can compile the app and run it fine! but it throws error if you hot restart or hot reload it? that is strange